# How to remove builtin padding from Icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It seems the `Icon` widget has a built-in padding, but I would like to remove the padding in order to properly align the icon with other widgets on the left side.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the widget itself is perfectly aligned to the left (I wrapped the `Icon` in a `Container` with background color just for testing purposes), but the icon has some padding and it looks missaligned.

Is there a possibility to remove this padding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the Icon implementation (you can take a look as well) and could not find anything about added padding. I am not 100% certain but I assume the whitespace is from the icon itself.

I have an alternative solution though:

1. Get the icon in SVG format (you can download Google Icons from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/icons)
2. Remove the padding using a SVG editor (you can use Figma Free version)
3. Add the icon as an asset in your pubspec.yaml

Good luck!